# ServiceStack.Razor - Requiring authentication on plain cshtml files

Tags: servicestack

I have been using a technique to secure my plain cshtml files (not backed by Services) in ServiceStack.  I will outline the technique I am using below.  However, the recent addition of Razor 2 support into ServiceStack has broken my implementation.

**Original Implementation**

```
using ServiceStack.Razor;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;

public class SecuredViewPage : ViewPage
{
    public override void Init(ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, ServiceStack.Html.ViewDataDictionary viewData, ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpRequest httpReq, ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpResponse httpRes)
    {
        new AuthenticateAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpRes, this);

        base.Init(viewEngine, viewData, httpReq, httpRes);
    }

}
```

Then in my cshtml files I have the following:

```
@inherits SecuredViewPage
```

The issue now is that in 3.9.94 the Init method is no longer an abstract method in **ViewPageBase**.

`My Questions`

**Is there is a better way to achieve this?**

or

**Should I see if ServiceStack will alter the implementation**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with my own solution to the problem. I am not sure how good this is as a solution, but it seems to work for me.

I essentially copied ViewPage.cs from the Servicestack source and stuck my authentication check in there.

```
public class SecuredViewPage : ViewPageBase<dynamic>, IRazorView
{
    public HtmlHelper Html = new HtmlHelper();

    public override Type ModelType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(DynamicRequestObject);
        }
    }

    public void Init(IViewEngine viewEngine, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes)
    {
        base.Request = httpReq;
        base.Response = httpRes;

        new AuthenticateAttribute().Execute(Request, Response, this);

        Html.Init(viewEngine: viewEngine, httpReq: httpReq, httpRes: httpRes, razorPage: this);
    }

    public override void SetModel(object o)
    {
        base.SetModel(o);
        Html.SetModel(o);
    }

    public void WriteTo(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        this.Output = Html.Writer = writer;
        this.Execute();
        this.Output.Flush();
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your authenticate attirbute?

Comment: It's the default ServiceStack Authenticate attribute.  Nothing custom in there.